# javac: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, runtime-error

I recently downloaded JDK 1.8.0.0_06 that comes bundled with NetBeans. I then got to find out that my JavaFx project, that I have been developing in Java 1.7 won't compile in Java 1.8, and so I stepped down my JDK to 1.7. Still I can't get it to work/ compile. I get this error:

```
javac: invalid target release: 1.8
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I'm really stuck and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: if you are going to step down, then change your project's source to 1.7 as well, right click on your `Project -> Properties -> Sources window` and set 1.7 here

Comment: You are a life saver @Jigar Joshi!!!! Thanks again***** a mill. Am so grateful. You could put your response as an answer so I can accept it. Wow! Again thank you. Had been stuck for so long!

Comment: If your project won't compile under Java 1.8, you are likely doing something pretty badly wrong (for example, you have static fields for the UI components in the code you posted in your other quetion, which is a serious design error). It's probably better to fix that problem than just to revert to a version from which many users will upgrade at some point in the future.

Comment: You are right @James_D. This is my first project in java. I pretty much taught myself programming, and wasn't getting the whole thing about avoiding static members, interfaces, and the rest about polymorphism till now. My project is a bit too big to be edited all at once. I plan to edit it and move to dependency injection via Spring bit by bit as I finish up on the other remaining areas. It's a painful lesson, but well learnt.

Comment: There are Java versions 1.8.0, 1.8.0_05, and 1.8.0_11, but there is no such thing as 1.8.0.0_06.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

if you are going to step down, then change your project's source to 1.7 as well,

```
right click on your Project -> Properties -> Sources window
```

and set `1.7` here

<sub>note: however I would suggest you to figure out why it doesn't work on 1.8</sub>

Answer (score 68):

For IntelliJ14 you may have to change the bytecode version w.r.t. the JDK you are using (in the global settings):

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me, changing Target bytecode version to 1.8 but get the same error

Comment: But the question was about Netbeans?

Answer (score 27):

1. Download [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
2. Edit your env var for `JAVA_HOME` to point to the new installed JDK 1.8:
   R-click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
   find `JAVA_HOME` on the list and set it's value to something like that:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
   ```
3. Find the old version and edit it in `PATH` variable aswell.
4. Probably you will need to restart the system.

Should be done.

Answer (score 25):

If this error occurs when running a Gradle (or Maven) task, you need to modify that build tool configuration to point to your installation of Java JDK 1.8 following this route:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

There you check the Linked Gradle project is the one you are working on and select the Gradle JVM (You missed this when you imported the gradle project into IntelliJ)

[image]

Remember when importing a Gradle (or Maven) project to set the target JVM correctly here:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Your javac is not pointing to correct java.

Check where your javac is pointing using following command -

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

If it is not pointed to the javac you want to compile with, point it to "/JAVA8_HOME/bin/javac", or which ever java you want to compile with.

Comment: why -1, I'd the same problem, and that was because my javac was not set to correct java version?

Comment: Mind that configuration may be broken the way java and javac are picked from different distributions!

Answer (score 9):

Most of the time, these type of issues happen due to incorrect java version. Make sure your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables are pointing to the correct version.

Comment: Yup - that was my cause too

Answer (score 5):

Maven setting:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous solutions worked for me.

I solved it by editing .idea/compiler.xml
There were "extra" (1) and (2) copies of the bad module with different targets.  I deleted the extraneous entried and changed the targets in the  section to 1.8 and it worked.

Comment: That fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate latest version as of 18th Dec 2017, if the above suggestions don't work, then please try the following: Right Click on the project and navigate to "Open Module Settings". Open it, then change the "Language Level" from the dropdown.

Comment: Also make sure that in Module Settings under the Dependencies tab the correct Module SDK is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

> if you are going to step down, then change your project's source to
>   1.7 as well,
>
> right click on your Project -> Properties -> Sources window  and set
>   1.7 here" Jigar Joshi

Also go to the `build-impl.xml` and look for the property `excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}"` and delete this property on my code was at line 827 but I`ve seen it on other lines

for me was taking a code from MAC OS java 1.8 to WIN XP java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,
I checked the pom.xml and 
changed

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

to

```
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
```

Comment: Gracias, this fixed it for me ,so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with netbeans, but mvn build is OK in cmd window. For me the issue resolved after changing netbeans' JDK (in netbeans.conf as below),

> netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"

Edit: Seems it's mentioned here: [netbeans bug 236364](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236364)

Answer (score 1):

Just do [this](https://www.david-merrick.com/2017/11/03/how-to-fix-invalid-target-release-error-in-intellij/). Then invalidate IntelliJ caches (`File -> Invalidate Caches`)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in  IntelliJ IDEA Community with Maven and I had to reimport the project by right-clicking the project in the Project tab -> Maven -> Reimport

Answer (score 0):

I've simply tricked the build system and put Java 8 path into Java 7 section of my Maven's toolchains.xml:

```
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.7.0_80</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <!--jdkHome>C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_80</jdkHome-->
      <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_281</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
```

Answer (score -1):

Installing a newer release of IDEA Community (2018.3 instead of 2017.x) was solved my issue with same error but java version:11. Reimport hadn't worked for me. But it worth a try.