# Not able to run Junit test cases in IntelliJ version : community 2017.2, error : Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'XXXXX'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

Not able to run Junit test cases in IntelliJ version : community 2017.2, same was working fine with old versions.

I have found two links [link1](http://Information:java:%20Errors%20occurred%20while%20compiling%20module) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878045/errorjava-invalid-source-release-8-in-intellij-what-does-it-mean) but not able to resolve the issue. Please help.

Error I am getting :

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'XXXXX'
Information:javac 7 was used to compile java sources
Information:18/10/17, 1:10 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2m 11s 343ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

The pom.xml has,

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Project gradle version

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-08-15 13:15:01 UTC
Revision:     ad76ba00f59ecb287bd3c037bd25fc3df13ca558

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.7.0_80-ea (Oracle Corporation 24.80-b07)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error-- does not tell much. Any more information? Logs from compiler?

Comment: Only this much.

Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'XXXXX'
Information:javac 7 was used to compile java sources
Information:18/10/17, 1:10 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2m 11s 343ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error

Comment: @BikramjitRajbongshi Try using the most recent Java 8 for the project instead of Java 7 EA build. Your code will still run on Java 7 since you set source/target versions. The issue seems to be caused by the old experimental Java 7 version.