# Why do I still get an invalid source release error when downgrading from Java 9 to Java 8?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-9

I downgraded my IntelliJ java project from java 9 to java 8. I followed all the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009627/9057492), but when running the project I still get this error: "Error: java: invalid source release: 1.9".

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>VIN_API</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven, Gradle or something?

Comment: I'm using maven, I'm sorry for leaving that out

Comment: Check your maven compiler plugin configuration. I'm sure that you are setting your Java version as java 9.

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Open the pom.xml file and replace the java release version value to 1.8

Comment: is that your complete pom.xml ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a new project and set the java version correctly from the beginning. I did that by following all the steps in the answer mentioned in the question. That solved the problem and the project is now running smoothly.