# VSAM file read maven dependency

Tags: java, file, vsam

I get below error when using the maven dependency to read IBM VSAM file. Could someone help?
groupId: com.ibm.jzos
artifactId: ibm.jzos
version:  3.1.3.1

*Error:
cannot access com.ibm.jzos.ZFile
bad class file: \c:\users\someone.m2\repository\com\ibm\jzos\ibm.jzos\3.1.3.1\ibm.jzos-3.1.3.1.jar(com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0 (IntelliJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640216/class-file-has-wrong-version-55-0-should-be-52-0-intellij)

Comment: Ok, I will try to use Java 11. Thank you!

Comment: This  worked! Thank you again.